# rails 3.1 generating CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am able to export table data to a CSV file, however there is a blank row after every record.  Why and how do i fix it?

in index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Export to csv", request.parameters.merge({:format => :csv})%>
```

in index.csv.erb

```
<%- headers = ["Id", "Name"] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<%- @customers.each do |n| -%>
<%- row = [ n.id, n.fname ] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line row %>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work. No blank row after every record. Maybe you need to inspect n.fname, you could have a new line char in the content of the field.

Comment: @MatteoAlessani Doesn't seem to be in the database records. Anywhere else i can look?  Can I just strip new lines out of the string before generating the row?

Comment: yes, you can try to strip them, or the field.

Comment: @MatteoAlessani I fixed it.  This line did the trick.  I think it has something to do with ruby's switch to fastercsv in ruby 1.9.  this line forces tab delimited values.  <%= CSV.generate_line row, :row_sep => ?\t, :quote_char => ?\ %>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what fixed it.

```
<%= CSV.generate_line row, :row_sep => ?\t, :quote_char => ?\ %>
```

Comment: I'd like to know more about that encoding.  Why the question mark?

Comment: From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm - You can get the integer value corresponding to an ASCII character or escape sequence by preceding it with a question mark.

Comment: This method adds an extra '0' at the end of each line for some reason. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 12):

`CSV.generate_line` adds a new line character to the end of the line it generates, but so does `<%= %>` so you're getting two new lines.

To suppress the new line character from the `erb` expression output use this syntax: `<%= -%>`

so:

```
<%- headers = ["Id", "Name"] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers -%>
<%- @customers.each do |n| -%>
<%- row = [ n.id, n.fname ] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line row -%>
<%- end -%>
```

The accepted answer leaves in the new line generated from the `erb` but suppresses the new line from `CSV.generate_line` which I think is not the best way to do it.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. I had initially resolved this issue with the use of .html_safe.strip. This worked until I had a double-quoted string with a comma in it. It messed up all my columns and was at a loss as to the solution until coming across this answer. My only suggestion is that you do not need the - on every line, it only has to be on the same line that has the =. Thank you so much!

Comment: this really should be the accepted answer. much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

for me following use of strip and html_safe worked, applied after the row was generated:

```
<%- headers = ["Id", "Tour No"] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line(headers).strip%>
<%- @tours.each do |t| -%>
<%-   row = [ t.id,t.tour_no] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line(row).html_safe.strip%>
<%- end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
row = [ n.id, n.fname.strip ]
```

strip will remove \r and/or \n which might cause the blank lines. I dont have any other explaination your sourcecode is okay!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would chip in with my solution as just been struggling with this.

Basically on my local machine (a mac) everything was working absolutely fine, then when I deployed my app to heroku it would start adding in these mystery new rows.

For me the solution was to use:

```
CSV.generate_line(row, row_step: ?\r).html_safe
```

As a note, I'm using rails 4.1.6.

Hope that helps some other people struggling