# rails csv.erb view includes whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have an index.csv.erb file with the following code:

```
<% headers = ['PrL', 'PrG', 'UOM', 'Quantity', 'Eff.Date', 'End Date','Price','Disc', 'P', 'Gr/Net'] %>
<%= CSV.generate_line(headers).strip.html_safe %>
<% @pricelist_price_groups.each do |pricelist_price_group| %>
  <% start_at = pricelist_price_group.start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y") unless pricelist_price_group.start_at.blank? %>
  <% end_at = pricelist_price_group.end_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y") unless pricelist_price_group.end_at.blank?  %>
<%= CSV.generate_line([pricelist_price_group.pricelist_id,
                         pricelist_price_group.price_group_id,
                         pricelist_price_group.sale_uom_id,
                         start_at,
                         end_at,
                         pricelist_price_group.price,
                         pricelist_price_group.disc_dollar,
                         pricelist_price_group.disc_percent,
                         pricelist_price_group.price_flag,
                         pricelist_price_group.gross_or_net]).strip.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

I add any whitespace such as

```
<% headers = ['PrL', 'PrG', 'UOM', 'Quantity', 'Eff.Date', 'End Date','Price','Disc', 'P', 'Gr/Net'] %>

<%= CSV.generate_line(headers).strip.html_safe %>
```

Then that whitespace is being written to the CSV file. Other cases include having two spaces as a tab before `<%= CSV.generate_line`

It has to be because that is the view that rails is rendering. If there a way I can still retain the use of whitespace to keep the code clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044793/1064619) in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812231/rails-3-1-generating-csv-file) Stack Overflow question.

i.e. use `strip` for the header row:

```
<%= CSV.generate_line(headers).strip%>
```

And `.html_safe.strip` for the content:

```
<%= CSV.generate_line(row).html_safe.strip%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the post [link](https://jonathanpike.net/2016/09/Exporting-CSV-From-Rails)  that work excellent.

```
<%- export = CSV.generate(" ", { headers: ["Array", "Of", "Headers"], write_headers: true, encoding: "UTF-8"}) do |csv| -%> 
<%- csv.add_row data -%> 
<%- end -%>
<%= export.lstrip.html_safe -%>
```